# How can I set textArea programmatically in Angular 2 using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an app built using the Angular 2 framework.  The app itself is working, but I am having an issue trying to set a textArea's value using JQuery in my testing scripts.  I've tried using all the JQuery methods I've seen online:

```
$("#myID").val("newVal");

$("#myID").val("newValue").trigger("input");

$("#myID").val("newValue").trigger("change");
```

Nothing seems to be working.  Is it possible to use JQuery on a textArea outside of the Angular 2 framework?  It won't even set in the console.

Comment: Sure, it should be possible. Not sure about testing scripts though. What does that even mean?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer We use Selenium testing that uses a Webdriver to run JQuery scripts.  So the test user wants to set the value of a text area, but any JQuery command I use specifically for a textArea doesn't get reflected in the UI or on the elemtn itself.  Other input fields work.

Comment: With Angular the DOM is still plain HTML and JS. I don't see why it wouldn't work. Could be a timing issue.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer My thought as well.  However, I am testing in the console (for now), so timing shouldn't be an issue.  IT works on any input field, but just not the textarea.

Comment: Does it work without Angular?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah, as soon as I remove 'ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"'' it works with the JQuery

Comment: That sounds more like messing with Angular, than testing without Angular ;-), but if it work this way, it should be good enough validation. If you add a `(change)="myHandler($event)"` to the element in Angular, does `myHandler(event) { ... }` get called? What is actually the exact behavior you are expecting from the code in your question?

Comment: Using `[(ngModel)]` with `textarea` listens for `input`, `blur`, `compositionstart`, and `compsitionend` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.3/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L33-L101, therefore `change` can be eliminated.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if the code was in my component, it wouldn't be so difficult, lol.  The problem I'm having is once the component is served, I am trying to run a JQuery script to target the value of a textarea tag.  So modifying the Angular 2 code doesn't help.  As of now, all I am trying to do is modify the text in an Angular 2 defined textarea in my console once the Angular 2 DOM element is initialized.

Comment: I didn't mean to change it permanently. I just try to find a way to figure out the cause of the issue.